# Making a Discord Bot in Python: How to make a toggle talk for a ChatBot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a discord ChatBot in Python and I seem to have come across a problem. I'm making a toggle on and off switch to make it talk but whenever I toggle that switch it says that 'talk' is not recognized as a command. I even tried making it @client.event instead of @client.command but it wouldn't work. Please help.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ":")
on_talk = False
@client.event
async def on_ready():
print("You can talk to me now!")
@client.command
async def talk(message):
    global on_talk
    if message.content.upper().startswith(":TALK"):
        on_talk = True
    if message.content.upper().startswith(":STOPTALK"):
        on_talk = False
if on_talk == False:
    print("on_talk is set to False")
if on_talk == True:
    print("It works")
```

EDIT: The talk function works but I can't seem to get the stoptalk function to work. I tried doing this.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ":")
on_talk = False
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("You can talk to me now!")
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ontalker(message):
    global on_talk
    if message.content.upper().startswith(":TALK"):
        on_talk = True

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def offtalker(message):    
    global ontalk
    if message.content.upper().startswith(":STOPTALK"):
        on_talk = False


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def stoptalk(ctx):
    print("on_talk is False.")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def talk(ctx):
    everything i want to do
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`client.command` *returns* a decorator, so you have to call it when decorating the coroutine.  If you want to pass the message, you have to specify `pass_context=True` and access the message through `ctx.message`.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def talk(ctx):
    global on_talk
    on_talk = True


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def stoptalk(ctx):
    global on_talk
    on_talk = False
```

Comment: So I replace the @client.command I had and put this in instead?

Comment: This would replace your entire `talk` coroutine.  This won't be case insensitive though.  There are already a few thread on how to accomplish that though.

Comment: Well, the talk function worked. I'm still tinkering around with the stoptalk function, but thanks for the clarification of this.